# Infering the size of a minipage from the containing tikz node for rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, tikz

This is a follow-up question to [Using bullets list in tikz's node label in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616781/using-bullets-list-in-tikzs-node-label-in-rmarkdown/56618770#56618770). I had some `TikZ` code that works fine in pure `LaTex` but NOT when I transport it to `rmarkdown` where the error `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` is raised. This was solved in the answer to [Using bullets list in tikz's node label in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616781/using-bullets-list-in-tikzs-node-label-in-rmarkdown/56618770#56618770) but another issue arises applying the solution I got in there.

You can refer to the original question ([Using bullets list in tikz's node label in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616781/using-bullets-list-in-tikzs-node-label-in-rmarkdown/56618770#56618770)) but basically I have some `TikZ` code for pictures to be used as part of a larger `rmarkdown` file. It works in `LaTex` as I tested in on https://www.overleaf.com/ but once in `rmarkdown`, it raises the missing item error. The proposed solution in [Using bullets list in tikz's node label in rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616781/using-bullets-list-in-tikzs-node-label-in-rmarkdown/56618770#56618770) was to add a `\minipage` environment in `rmarkdown` (see the code below).

My problem with the use of the `\minipage` environment is that I will have to manually set its width (or at least I don't know how to automate this) before creating the node which is supposed to be part of a large `TikZ` picture. In other words, I need to know the allocated space for each node to reproduce the picture in `rmarkdown`. I was wondering whether there is a way to infer the size of the node in advance, so that I can create a minipage matching the size of the node it will contain.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{BulletsColor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.9}
\newlist{myBullets}{itemize}{1}

\setlist[myBullets]{
  label=\textcolor{BulletsColor}{\textbullet},
  leftmargin=*,
  topsep=0ex,
  partopsep=0ex,
  parsep=0ex,
  itemsep=0ex,
  before={\color{BulletsColor}\itshape}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, rounded corners] (a)  {
    \begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
      p
      \begin{myBullets}
      \item first item
      \item second item
      \end{myBullets}
    \end{minipage}
  }
  ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am also open to other solutions as long as I will NOT have to specify the size of my nodes manually. For example doing (note the commented lines)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, rounded corners] (a)  {
    % \begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
      p
      \begin{myBullets}
      \item first item
      \item second item
      \end{myBullets}
    % \end{minipage}
  }
  ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

in `TikZ` will infer the size of the node from its text size and I am looking for something that allows me to use the same code in `rmarkdown` without having to manually specify the size of each minipage across my nodes.

Comment: Probably unrelated to the problem, but the use of a minipage in the tikz node seems overkill. I suggest to simply specify the text width, e.g. `\node[draw, rounded corners,text width = 3cm] (a){
p
\begin{myBullets}
\item first item
\item second item
\end{myBullets}
};`

Comment: "Infering the size of a minipage from the containing tikz node for rmarkdown" You can't, if you are in paragraph mode. A paragraph takes as much space as it can before line breaking. So a paragraph, without any mean to compute its size is a TeX error.

Comment: If you dont want the minipage, you can use `\node[draw,text width=3cm](a){P, etc}` If you dont want the fixed width, replace it by `1.2\widthof{my item width}` that will scale with your fonts (with the calc package). But you need to introduce some width. And a last word. Your documents will probably look nicer if all nodes have the same size (or you have a limited set of differents sizes). So even if it was possible, I do not think it woud be a good idea to have node width completely adapt to the actual text.

Comment: @samcarter, this works fine in rmarkdown but I also need my style (set up as stile namely)

Comment: @Alain Merigot, I will give a try to the same size node idea. I haven't even thought about having the same node size may give a better look to the whole picture.

Comment: @Liman Did you try to add `namely` to the node options?

Comment: @samcarter Thank you for answer and comments. I have been trying to test it and make sure it solves my problem before accepting it. I just added my style and it works though with some warnings. Basically, instead of   `\node[draw, rounded corners, font=\itshape, text=BulletsColor] (a)  {...}`, I just used   `\node[stile] (a)  {...}`.

Comment: @samcarter I am not aware of  `namely` as node option. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Liman I understood your comment as if  your style was called `namely`, but apparently it is called something else.

Comment: @samcarter Oh! I called it `stile`.

Comment: @Liman I have yet to learn how to read minds :)

Comment: @samcarter fair enough! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace `minipage` with the `varwidth` environment from the package of the same name:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{varwidth}


\begin{document}
\definecolor{BulletsColor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.9}
\newlist{myBullets}{itemize}{1}

\setlist[myBullets]{
  label=\textcolor{BulletsColor}{\textbullet},
  leftmargin=*,
  topsep=0ex,
  partopsep=0ex,
  parsep=0ex,
  itemsep=0ex,
%  before={\color{BulletsColor}\itshape}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, rounded corners, font=\itshape, text=BulletsColor] (a)  {
    \begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
      p
      \begin{myBullets}
      \item \textcolor{BulletsColor}{first item}
      \item \textcolor{BulletsColor}{second item}
      \end{myBullets}
    \end{varwidth}
  }
  ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]