# Knit rmarkdown files containing tikz chunks while using fontspec package

Tags: latex, r-markdown, knitr, tikz, fontspec

This is a follow-up question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616781/using-bullets-list-in-tikzs-node-label-in-rmarkdown) then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633052/infering-the-size-of-a-minipage-from-the-containing-tikz-node-for-rmarkdown) one. I am trying to include some`TikZ` code into an `rmarkdown` file. The [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616781/using-bullets-list-in-tikzs-node-label-in-rmarkdown) solved the problem about using bullets in node label whereas the [second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56633052/infering-the-size-of-a-minipage-from-the-containing-tikz-node-for-rmarkdown) added the use of `varwidth` instead of `minipage` environment.

Adding the `fontspec` package raised another problem I can't seem to solve. The following error is raised whenever I added the package in my list:

`! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
(fontspec)

(fontspec)                      You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec)                      e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of
(fontspec)                      "latex" or "pdflatex".`

Following the previous answers, the code is composed of the following 2 files:

- `Title.Rmd`:

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
---


```{tikz tikz-ex, echo=FALSE, fig.cap = "Funky tikz", fig.ext = 'pdf', cache=FALSE, eval=TRUE, engine.opts = list(template = "tikz2pdf.tex")}
\usetikzlibrary{
shapes,
arrows
}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[stile] (a){
\begin{minipage}{2.5cm}
p
\begin{myBullets}
\item first item
\item second item
\end{myBullets}
\end{minipage}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
```
````

- `tikz2pdf.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{
tikz,
enumitem,
xcolor
}

\usepackage{fontspec} % new adding to previous answers
\setromanfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{BulletsColor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.9}
\definecolor{myColor}{rgb}{0.98, 0.94, 0.9}
\newlist{myBullets}{itemize}{1}

\setlist[myBullets]{
  label=\textcolor{BulletsColor}{\textbullet},
  leftmargin=*,
  topsep=0ex,
  partopsep=0ex,
  parsep=0ex,
  itemsep=0ex,
  before={\color{BulletsColor}\itshape}
}

\tikzstyle {stile} = [
ellipse,
draw=BulletsColor,
fill=myColor,
thick,
inner sep=0pt,
text centered, 
align=center
]

\begin{preview}
%% TIKZ_CODE %%
\end{preview}

\end{document}
```

From the error message above, I understand I am in `pdflatex` mode while `fontspec` requires me to be in `xelatex` or `lualatex` mode. Given that I have `latex_engine: xelatex` in my header, this torments me with the following questions:

- why does setting `latex_engine: xelatex` in the header is unsufficient here?
- Does the `knitr` chunk not care about the `latex_engine: xelatex` in the header? If so, how can I solve that?
- What am I missing?

I have been searching around and one suggestion (that is not overly complicated to me) is to make sure the global / project settings are set to `weave rnw files using: knitr`, `Typeset LateX into pdf using: XeLaTex`. But, this has not really helped solving my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143900/8416610 you have to tell `tinytex::latexmk` to use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` by using `options(tinytex.engine = 'xelatex')` in a set-up chunk.

In addition, you should update your `tikz2pdf.tex` for compatibility with XeTeX:

- Remove option `pdftex` from package `preview`
- Remove package `inputenc`.

With these changes your document works for me.

Comment: Sorry for delayed reaction! I got held elsewhere. Otherwise, this solved my problem. Thanks.